# How to correctly assign types of props in next js while using typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js

This is my index.tsx file:

```
    import type { NextPage } from "next";
    
    type AppProps = {
      articles: {
        userId: number;
        id: number;
        title: string;
        body: string;
      };
    };
    
    const Home: NextPage = ({articles}:AppProps) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Welcome to {articles.title}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    const articles = await res.json();
    
      return {
        props: { articles },
      };
    };
 export default Home;
```

The code did get rendered but there is an error in my `Home` component.
It shows the following error message:

```
Type '({ articles }: AppProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'NextPage<{}, {}>'.
  Type '({ articles }: AppProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext): {} | Promise<{}>; }'.
    Type '({ articles }: AppProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
        Property 'articles' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'AppProps'.
```

Is there anything i am doing wrong? I could not figure it out. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NextPage` is [based on](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/937ab16b780dc2bc755fa9c032ffe498c79b5af6/packages/next/types/index.d.ts#L55-L58) `NextComponentType` which has [a type parameter list](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/ffdb9f847f7b74db7daae43aa1440bd3162d76d1/packages/next/shared/lib/utils.ts#L10-L21) with default values (`{}`) for initial page data (`props`):

```
// With no type arguments passed in, `props` is of type `{}`
const Home: NextPage = () => { /*...*/ }
```

When passing `props` to a `NextPage` component, you'll also need to pass in your type as an argument.

This will be a TypeScript error because `articles` does not exist on type `{}`:

```
// The `AppProps` annotation types the function argument itself, but with
// no type arguments passed to `NextPage`, `props` is still of type `{}`
const Home: NextPage = ({ articles }: AppProps) => { /*...*/ }
```

So to give `NextPage` type information about `props`, pass `AppProps` in as a type argument like this:

```
// you can omit the type annotation from the function argument as `AppProps`
// will be inferred
const Home: NextPage<AppProps> = ({ articles }) => { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: It worked but i am unfamiliar with this syntax. Could you please explain this?

Comment: @kob003 Please see revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InferGetStaticPropsType` or `InferGetServerSidePropsType` as needed.

Using your example:

```
    import type { InferGetStaticPropsType } from "next";
    
    type Article = {
      userId: number;
      id: number;
      title: string;
      body: string;
    };
    
    const Home = ({articles}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Welcome to {articles.title}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    const articles: Article[] = await res.json();
    
      return {
        props: { articles },
      };
    };
 export default Home;
```